# laravel how to get use with relation in blade after login

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and the User model has relation with model UserProfile
as following

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
.
.
.
public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class,'user_id');
    }
}
```

when i create a new user i directly do login for him and redirect him to dashboard
as following

```
 Auth::login($user, true);

return $this->sendSuccessResponse();
```

but my question is how i can use user data with it's userProfile relation in blade or controller
I tried to use the following code in blade

```
<img src="{{Auth::user()->profile->image}}" id="profile-img" alt="">
```

but i get the following error message

> Attempt to read property "image" on null

Comment: have you`dd(Auth::user()->profile);` ??

Comment: yes but it return null

Comment: what about `Auth::user()` ?

Comment: What does your database look like for these tables?

Comment: Auth::user() is exists but the relation is null does this code return user with relations Auth::login($user, true);

Comment: sorry i found the mistake i didn't add relation in online version it was different  code between my local and my online version i will delete the post

Answer (score 0):

Your `profile` relationship is either malformed or missing.

This error means that you are trying to get the property `image` on a value of `null`.

That's because `Auth::user()->profile` returns `null`, then `Auth::user()->profile->image` is like writing `(null)->image`.

This can be caused by several things:

- Missing data in the database
- Wrong columns name
- Wrong tables name

The easiest thing to bypass this error would be to only display the image when this relationship isn't `null`:

```html
@if(Auth::user()->profile !== null)
    <img src="{{Auth::user()->profile->image}}" id="profile-img" alt="">
@endif
```

However, it would be better to understand why it's `null`, at least to avoid further problems in your project.

Comment: yes i understand the problem the system doesn't return relations with user but does this code Auth::login($user, true); correct and return user with his relations or not ?

Comment: sorry i found the mistake i didn't add relation in online version it was different  code between my local and my online version i will delete the post

Answer (score 0):

Apply these changes in your User model. I think it will work for you.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        /**
         * The relationships that should always be loaded.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $with = ['profile'];
    
        /**
         * Get the user profile.
         */
        public function profile()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not change anything. The relation is lazy loaded, so there is no need to add it to the `$with` array.

Comment: sorry i found the mistake i didn't add relation in online version it was different  code between my local and my online version i will delete the post